# how to filter by day with pandas

Tags: pandas

I am reading a series of data from file via pd.read_csv().
Then somehow I create a dataframe like the following:

```
              col1   col2
01/01/2001     a1      a2
02/01/2001     b1      b2
03/01/2001     c1      c2
04/01/2001     d1      d2
01/01/2002     e1      e2
02/01/2002     f1      d2
03/01/2002     g1      g2
04/01/2002     h1      h2
```

What I would like to do is to groub by the same day, and assign to it a value, I mean:

```
         col1
01/01     ax     
02/01     bx     
03/01     cx     
04/01     dx
```

Does anyone have any clues how to perform this smoothly?

Thanks a lot in advance.

LS

Comment: Is the data type of your `index` datetime or object/string? You can verify with `df.index.dtype`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I'd do is make sure your index are dates.  If you know they are, then skip this.

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Then you `groupby` with something like `[df.index.month, df.index.day]` or `df.index.strftime('%m-%d')`.  However, you have to choose to aggregate or transform.  You didn't specify what you wanted to do, so I chose the `first` function to aggregate.

```
df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%m-%d')).first()

      col1 col2
01-01   a1   a2
02-01   b1   b2
03-01   c1   c2
04-01   d1   d2
```